# Node modules broken When using Vite + React + Apollo Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, vite, apollo-client

I tried `@apollo/client` with [this starting apollo client document](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started) but wanted to use Vite instead of CRA. I imported the modules in `main.jsx` like this:

```js
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
  gql,
} from "@apollo/client/core";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://flyby-router-demo.herokuapp.com/",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

// ...

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

and then my app crushed with this message

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical chunk-NWQ2EI35.js:1493:112
```

In "chunk-NWQ2EI35.js:1493:112" I could see this js code.

```js
// node_modules/graphql/jsutils/instanceOf.mjs
var _globalThis$process;
var instanceOf = (
  /* c8 ignore next 6 */
  // FIXME: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/2317

  // !!! THIS is the line #1493 !!!
  ((_globalThis$process = globalThis.process) === null || _globalThis$process === void 0 ? void 0 : _globalThis$"development") === "production" ? function instanceOf2(value, constructor) { 

  // ...
```

Source from `node_modules/graphql/jsutils/instanceOf.js` :

```js
const instanceOf =
  /* c8 ignore next 6 */
  // FIXME: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/2317
  ((_globalThis$process = globalThis.process) === null ||
  _globalThis$process === void 0
    ? void 0
    : _globalThis$process.env.NODE_ENV) === 'production'
    ? function instanceOf(value, constructor) {
        return value instanceof constructor;
      }
    : function instanceOf(value, constructor) {
        if (value instanceof constructor) {
          return true;
        }

    // ...
```

Seems `_globalThis$process.env.NODE_ENV` changed to `_globalThis$"development"`, and this caused the problem.

I have no idea how to use apollo client with vite environment. Needed some helps based on your experiences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same issue appeared in my project (Nuxt 3, Cloudflare Pages preset), even with `graphql` version `16.7.1`.

Not need to downgrade, it is fixed in `17.0.0-alpha.2`.

Add this to your `package.json`:

```
  "overrides": {
    "graphql": "^17.0.0-alpha.2"
  }
```

Comment: `17.0.0-alpha.2` is 9 months old, and the next release of v17 will contain the same change. If this still causes problems, please create a reproduction and open an issue - at this point the maintainers assume that all problems should be fixed with `16.7.1`. If that is not the case, you'll have to draw their attention to it.

Comment: Aha, havent noticed it, thanks.

Comment: Reported here: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/3928

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by a `graphql` version update from yesterday. A new release to fix this is in the works, meanwhile you can downgrade `graphql` to `16.6.0`.

---

Edit: this should be fixed with 16.7.1 now.

Comment: Wow what a coincidence.